# Why does this trivial usage of PyArray_SimpleNewFromData segfault?

Tags: python, c, numpy

I'm trying to use NumPy in a C extension for python.

I'm getting a segfault I can't explain, I've narrowed it down to this simple example.

```
#include "numpy/arrayobject.h"

int main()
{
    int dims[] = {1};
    double d[] = {1};

    PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dims, NPY_DOUBLE, &d);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.how-to-extend.html

> This function must be declared so that it is visible to code outside
>   of the routine. **Besides adding the methods and constants you desire,
>   this subroutine must also contain calls like import_array()** and/or
>   import_ufunc() depending on which C-API is needed. Forgetting to place
>   these commands will show itself as an **ugly segmentation fault** (crash)
>   as soon as any C-API subroutine is actually called.

I also had to include `Py_Initialize()` beforehand since this was a standalone example not being run through a Python vm as it would normally be.